# Class/Object that can store either a JTextField or JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, object, custom-controls

I would like to create my own Class/Object that can store either a JTextField or JComboBox under
the same variable. This is what I have so far:

```
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Parameter {

String name;
String type;
String value;
JComponent comp;

Parameter(String inName, String inType, String inValue) {

    this.name = inName.trim();
    this.type = inType.trim();
    this.value = inValue.trim();

    // Set Component Type
    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("bool")) {
        String[] tfArray = { "Yes", "No" };
        comp = new JComboBox(tfArray);
        comp.setFocusable(false);
        ((JComboBox)comp).setSelectedItem(value.trim());

    } else {
        comp = new JTextField(value);
    }

}// End Parameter Constructor

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public JComponent getComp() {
    return comp;
}

}// End Parameter Class
```

I Then have an ArrayList that stores my Parameter Objects. The Name/Type/Value is actually coming from an XML file but I have simplified the code for an example:

```
static ArrayList<Parameter> parameterArray = new ArrayList<Parameter>();

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
parameterArray.add(new Parameter(parameterName,parameterType,value));
}
```

I Then Add the Components to a JPanel.. e.g.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++){
panel.add(parameterArray.get(i).getComp());
}
```

It All works fine up to this stage! I get ComboBoxes/JTextFields As Expected. However when I try
to retrieve the text/SelectedItem it is giving me the value from when the Parameter object was first initialized e.g.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  if(parameterArray.get(i).getType.equalsIgnoreCase("bool"){
    value = ((JComboBox)parameterArray.get(i).getComp()).getSelectedItem().toString();
  }else{
    value = ((JTextField)parameterArray.get(i).getComp()).getText();
  }
}
```

The Issue is that If i modify the JComboBox or The JTextField from the interface.. it is still using the value from when it was initialized.. Not the newly modified value. Any Ideas??

Thanks

Tim

Comment: How you modifiy your values? Do you propagate your changes to the component?

Comment: print `((JComboBox)parameterArray.get(i).getComp()).getSelectedIndex()` to see if you have a problem selecting the items, or retrieving the item selected

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the quick responses. Sergiy.. I was hoping that when the user modifies the value in the JComboBox/JTextField, the value would automatically update? Like It would if I was using a standard JComboBox/JTextField Outside the 'Parameter' Class? DSquare.. I will try that now and see the result! Though I don't think it is an issue selecting the item, as the user can modify the value, it's just an issue retrieving the data. Thanks

Comment: are you sure, the values aren't changed? maybe your GUI doesn't repaint properly?

Comment: I've given up and approached this in a completely different way! Now have separate Arrays for both My Parameters and My JTextFields. Would have been nice to know why It didnt work but nevermind. Thansk for all your help.

Comment: Just an update on this.. In case anyone comes across the same thing. I ended up creating a CustomTextField Class that extends JTextField, then created a field within this class that contains a 'Parameter' Object and this worked fine.